# How do I create custom routes in Ruby on Rails - 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have the route as below;

```
resources :invoices do
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'invoices#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
end
```

But I would like to get **'deliveries#search'** instead of **'invoices#search'**.

I successfully customized for the below routes;

```
get 'deliveries', to: 'invoices#index', as: :deliveries

get 'deliveries/new', to: 'invoices#new', as: :delivery

get 'deliveries/:id/edit', to: 'invoices#edit', :as => :del
```

I have tried but unable to customized for the 'deliveries#search'.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resources :invoices, path: 'deliveries' do
 collection do
  match 'search' => 'invoices#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
 end
end
```

it will generate route with prefix deliveries like `/deliveries/your_action`

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes as follows

```
resources :deliveries, controller: 'invoices', only: [:index, :new, :edit]
resources :deliveries, only: [] do
  collection do
    get :search
    post :search
  end 
end
```

This will generate following routes for you:

```
        deliveries GET  /deliveries(.:format)           invoices#index
      new_delivery GET  /deliveries/new(.:format)       invoices#new
     edit_delivery GET  /deliveries/:id/edit(.:format)  invoices#edit
search_deliveries  GET  /deliveries/search(.:format)    deliveries#search
                   POST /deliveries/search(.:format)    deliveries#search
```

**EDIT**

According to your comment I think you just need to use different  controller

Try this

```
resources :deliveries, controller: 'invoices', only: [:index, :new, :edit] do
  collection do
    get :search
    post :search
  end
end
```

This will generate following routes:

```
search_deliveries  GET  /deliveries/search(.:format)    invoices#search
                   POST /deliveries/search(.:format)    invoices#search
        deliveries GET  /deliveries(.:format)           invoices#index
      new_delivery GET  /deliveries/new(.:format)       invoices#new
     edit_delivery GET  /deliveries/:id/edit(.:format)  invoices#edit
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I can't do this as I have got invoices controller and invoice model.What I want is when I do the search instead of showing http://localhost:3000/invoices/search I want to show as http://localhost:3000/deliveries/search.

Comment: so you just want to show them as `/deliveries/search` but you want to use `invoices` controller

Comment: Thanks.That is working fine but when I go to new or edit actions it gives me the errors as NoMethodError in Invoices#edit and the extracted source it is showing as , <%= simple_form_for(@invoice) do |f| %>

Comment: you might need to change your `path_name` acordingly as they are changed to `new_delivery_path` and `edit_delivery_path`