# change url name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a route in my rails application:

```
get 'welcome/usertypeone' => 'welcome#usertypeone'
```

This doesnot look good in the browser as the URL comes out like:

```
www.mywebsite/welcome/usertypeone
```

Any way I could change the way the url looks to something like:

```
www.mywebsite/welcome/teacher
```

without needing to change the route itself as i would need to change it in loads of places. Just seeing if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503550/route-alias-in-rails

Comment: check my answer here for creating custom route names https://stackoverflow.com/a/39464704/5934752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're explicitly defining the route (as you are, as opposed to using `resource` etc) you can configure the route as you'd like.

```
get 'welcome/teacher' => 'welcome#usertypeone'
```

This will make `www.mywebsite.com/welcome/teacher` route to the same controller and action.

You will, however, need to update the route throughout your application from `welcome_usertypeone_path` to `welcome_teacher_path`. Your text editor probably has a search and replace function making this a 10 second step.

Comment: Re the last part, if it's a huge pain to replace all paths, you could add the `as` option, i.e. `get 'welcome/teacher' => 'welcome#usertypeone', as: 'welcome_usertypeone'`. [More here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#generating-paths-and-urls-from-code).

Comment: @SRack brings up a great point. It depends on how particular you are on cruft and technical debt (like keeping old things around because of fear of updating), but `as:` is definitely viable here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want looks like this:

```
get 'welcome/:user_type' => 'welcome#usertypeone'
```

This will take whatever is after the `welcome/` and put it in `params` as `params[:user_type]`, but it will still go to the `WelcomesController` and the `usertypeone` action.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to your `routes.rb` file and try:

`get 'welcome/teacher' => 'welcome#usertypeone'`

Then you should get the url you require: `www.mywebsite/welcome/teacher`